# Connectedness implies path-connectedness (in graphs)

Tags: general-topology

I am curious how to prove the following, which is claimed without proof in some notes.

Let $\Gamma$ be a (countable) graph. Let $X$ be the topological realization of $\Gamma$. Supposing $X$ is connected, deduce $X$ is path-connected.

Comment: Hint: Show that the path connected component containing point $x\in\Gamma$ is both opened and closed. Basically, the set and it’s complement are unions of edges. Use the definition of $\Gamma$ to show both sets are closed.

Comment: ah I see. that seems to make sense. I might try to work out the details tomorrow.